# Append parameters to an existing PSCustomObject 'op_Addition' error in powershell

Tags: powershell

Trying to parse through an Azure parameters template from gihub and update some parameters to the file in Powershell then commit it back to github for automation purposes.  I seem to be erroring out on adding the new parameters back in to the file pulled from github.  I've checked and made sure the objects are both the same.

I pull the JSON file down from github fine, convert it from JSON, compile my new parameter object and when i go to add the new parameters back into the original i receive the below error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $paramTemplate.parameters += $newparam
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Powerhell code:

```
#Get Content
$paramContent = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $parameterUri -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing).content 
$paramTemplate = $paramContent | ConvertFrom-Json

#define parameters in JSON Format
$addnewparam = @"
    {
    "parameters": {
        "virtualMachineRG": {
            "value": "$virtualMachineRG"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "value": "$virtualMachineName"
        },
        "virtualMachineSize" : {
            "value": "$virtualMachineSize"
        },
        "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
            "value": "$diagnosticsStorageAccountName"
        }
    }
    }
"@

$newparam = $addnewparam | ConvertFrom-JSON
$paramTemplate.parameters += $newparam
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

```
PS C:\GitHub\Azure> $paramtemplate.GetType()
>>

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object


PS C:\GitHub\Azure> $newparam.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

I've also tried matching the NoteProperty the same for both to no avail.  I'm on PSVersion                      5.1.17763.771

```
PS C:\GitHub\Azure> $paramtemplate | get-member


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name           MemberType   Definition
----           ----------   ----------
Equals         Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode    Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType        Method       type GetType()
ToString       Method       string ToString()
$schema        NoteProperty string $schema=https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#
contentVersion NoteProperty string contentVersion=1.0.0.0
parameters     NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject parameters=@{subnetName=; virtualNetworkId=; virtualMachineName=; virtualMachineRG=; osDiskType=; virtualMachineSize=; admi...


PS C:\GitHub\Azure> $newparam | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
parameters  NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject parameters=@{virtualMachineRG=; virtualMachineName=; virtualMachineSize=; diagnosticsStorageAccountName=}
```

Comment: `.parameters` is not a collection so you can’t add to it until it is. `$paramtemplate.parameters = ,$paramtemplate.parameters + $newparam` should work. The comma unary operator makes it a collection for your first addition.

Comment: That did seem to add it into the parameters, but looked to add an additional parameter section to the object.  This will not work later on in that i will have some duplicate parameters in the file.  There are only a handful or parameters i'm looking to update from the original

Comment: ```
PS C:\GitHub\Azure> $paramTemplate.parameters
virtualMachineName            : @{value=palmer-tst}
virtualMachineRG              : @{value=AZ-EA-RG-SBX.}
virtualMachineSize            : @{value=Standard_B2ms}
diagnosticsStorageAccountName : @{value=azeargsbxpalmerne2361}

parameters : @{virtualMachineRG=; virtualMachineName=; virtualMachineSize=; diagnosticsStorageAccountName=}
```

Comment: ah i thought the code snippet would work.

Comment: but basically i need to update the parameters in the original rather than add an additional section.  perhaps it may not be feasible to even update them

Comment: `$addnewparam` has variables in it. How will those get updated with real values?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if you want to update `$paramtemplate.parameters` property values with values from `$newparam.parameters` properties.

```
$newparam.parameters.PSObject.Properties.Name | Foreach-Object { 
    $paramtemplate.parameters.$_ = $newparam.parameters.$_
}
```

Since you are dealing with a `PSCustomObject` type in `.parameters`, `.PSObject.Properties` will return all of its properties. The `.Name` property returns the string name of the properties. `$_` is the current object being processed within `Foreach-Object { }` script block.

---

You could do this slightly differently, which is uglier (IMO) but could be negligibly more performant.

```
$newparam.parameters.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object { 
    $paramtemplate.parameters.$($_.Name) = $_.Value
}
```

---

**Note:** If `$newparam` contains properties that `$paramtemplate` does not have, then we will have to add more logic to handle that case.

```
$newparam.parameters.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object { 
    if ($paramtemplate.parameters.PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $_.Name) {
        $paramtemplate.parameters.$($_.Name) = $_.Value
    }
    else {
        $paramtemplate.parameters | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value
    }
}
```

---

Regarding the error message you received, this happened because you were attempting to add a `PSCustomObject` to another `PSCustomObject`. That type of operation requires your first object to be a collection. You can convert an object to a collection using the unary operator `,` just before you add the next object. The syntax is as follows:

```
$object1 = ,$object1 + $object2
```

**EDIT**

Looking more closely at these objects, it appears that all of the properties contain another `PSCustomObject` with a property called `Value` with some value that you will have supplied. In that case, the following will work for updating the template.

```
$newparam.parameters.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object { 
    if ($paramtemplate.parameters.PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $_.Name) {
        $paramtemplate.parameters.$($_.Name).Value = $_.Value.Value
    }
    else {
        $paramtemplate.parameters | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value ([pscustomobject]@{Value = $_.Value.Value})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newparam | ForEach {
  $paramtemplate.parameters | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value
}
```

This iterates over the psobject to add and adds properties one by one.